# Sitecore: Cannot get all the values inside of a multi-list item

Tags: xml, xslt, sitecore, xslt-2.0, sitecore6

For example I can get to a Profile created in Sitecore  and I can get it's name.

(Sitecore) Settings > Profile > UserTypes > Entertainment Executive > AR Executive

```
<xsl:variable name="ARExec" select="$UserTypes/item[3]/item[1]"/>
```

The above code will print out **AR Executive**

Now inside of **AR Executive** I have a **Multilist named Related Genre Types**, and inside that are:

- Music
- Comedy
- TV

I've been trying to follow this example here:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/Accessing%20Field%20Values/Multilist.aspx

However I cannot reproduce the results, I want to be able to get and list out all 3 names, but it only let's me grab Music, the first item. I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the items in the Multilist and display them all.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
....    

<xsl:variable name="ARExec" select="$UserTypes/item[3]/item[1]"/>

<lable><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Related Genre Types', $ARExec)"/></lable>

<xsl:variable name="ids" select="concat(sc:fld('Related Genre Types',$ARExec),'|')"/>

<xsl:call-template name="PrintTitles">
    <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="$ids"/>
</xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PrintTitles">
  <xsl:param name="ids"/>
  <xsl:if test="$ids">
    <xsl:variable name="itm_id" select="substring-before($ids, '|')"/>
    <xsl:if test="$itm_id">
      <xsl:variable name="itm" select="sc:item($itm_id,.)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Title', $itm)"/> &amp; 

    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="PrintTitles">
      <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-after($ids, '|')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

^ Prints out {id number...}Music &

[image: Sitecore editor]

**How do I loop through the my Multilist to grab and print out all 3 items?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to target the owner of the Multilist item differently, I had to target it using @key then the [example code](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/Accessing%20Field%20Values/Multilist.aspx) worked:

```
<xsl:variable name="ExecUser" select="$UserTypes/item[@key='entertainment executive']" />
```

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, you'll need something like the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="item" select="$usertypes/item[3]/item[1]" />

<xsl:for-each select="sc:Split('related genre types', $item)>
    <xsl:variable name="fielditem" select="sc:item(.,.)"/>
    <sc:text field="title" select="$fielditem]/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My apologies for the formatting, I'm on my phone.

**[edit]**
In the Split function we don't need to call sc:fld().

Comment: hmm I'm getting an "Xsl file could not be processed" error now, I'm starting over from scratch, to see if I can redo this, thanks for taking a moment to have a look at this!

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out, had to use a key to target the 'Profile' I was trying to get the Multilist of: <xsl:variable name="ExecUser" select="$UserTypes/item[@key='entertainment executive']" />

Comment: I'm aware you've already figured it out - I did fix the XSLT code still though. 
One last thing: If you have an error "Xsl file could not be processed", you can usually click on the exclamation mark to show some more details on the error.